# Synchronized Threading With Semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I am trying to synchronize some threads using semaphores. The goal is to repeatedly print a sequence of 1's (8 times), 2's (4 times), 4's (2 times), and 8's (1 time) in that order.  My program works correctly until it is about 90% complete, and then it messes up on the 2's and 4's. I can't figure out for the life of me what might be causing the issue. Any suggestions?

```
public class ThreadSync
{

private static int count = 100;

private static Semaphore printSomeOnes = new Semaphore(1);
private static Semaphore printSomeTwos = new Semaphore(0);
private static Semaphore printSomeFours = new Semaphore(0);
private static Semaphore printSomeEights = new Semaphore(0);


private static boolean runFlag = true;

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    // create and start each runnable
    Runnable task1 = new TaskPrint1();
    Runnable task2 = new TaskPrint2();
    Runnable task3 = new TaskPrint4();
    Runnable task4 = new TaskPrint8();

    Thread thread1 = new Thread( task1 );
    Thread thread2 = new Thread( task2 );
    Thread thread3 = new Thread( task3 );
    Thread thread4 = new Thread( task4 );

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();
    thread4.start();



    // Let them run for 500ms
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // put up the stop sign
    runFlag=false;

    thread4.interrupt();
    thread3.interrupt();
    thread2.interrupt();
    thread1.interrupt();

}

public static class TaskPrint1 implements Runnable 
{
    public void run(){
        while (runFlag) {
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                if(i % 8 == 0){
                try {                       
                    printSomeOnes.acquire();                        
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.printf( "%s\n", "1");
            if(i % 8 == 0){
            printSomeTwos.release();
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class TaskPrint2 implements Runnable 
{
    public void run(){
        while (runFlag) {
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                if(i % 4 == 0){
                try {
                    printSomeTwos.acquire();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.printf( "%s\n", "2");
            if(i % 4 == 0){
            printSomeFours.release();
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class TaskPrint4 implements Runnable 
{
    public void run(){
        while (runFlag) {
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                if(i % 2 == 0){
                try {
                    printSomeFours.acquire();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.printf( "%s\n", "4");
            if(i % 2 == 0){
            printSomeEights.release();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class TaskPrint8 implements Runnable 
{
    public void run(){
        while (runFlag) {
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
                try {
                    printSomeEights.acquire();
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.printf( "%s\n", "8");
            printSomeOnes.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Unless your task is an exercise in the use of semaphores, consider using 4 queues (for ones, twos, fours, and eights), posting to them in your worker threads and reading from them in order in your main thread.

Comment: Also why are you forcefully interrupting threads?  Try just joining the last one if you can guarantee it will run/terminate.

Comment: Are you expecting the threads to run in a particular order? You cannot predict the behaviour of the Thread Scheduler and hence the 2s and 4s are getting messed up. You will have to use join if you want the threads to order one after the other

Comment: Yes, it's a semaphore exercise. We can't use anything except semaphore-related statements, so I don't think I can add any joins. I see what you guys are saying though.

Comment: If you are using semaphores, I think you need to adjust your looping scheme, right now, printing 100 seems odd to me, and it definitely does not do what you think it does. I think you also need to revisit what the `%` does, since `if (i % 2 == 0)` does not cause it to print twice in the context. Maybe I'm missunderstanding what you're trying to do, but either way, check out the Java tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Some changes that i have done:

Remove the  `runFlag` use `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`, which is the best way to deal this situation. And when ever `InterruptedException` occurs just reset the interrupt flag for the thread so that the code in the higher order will act on it. 
As:

```
                     try {
                            printSomeOnes.acquire();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            break;
                        }
```

Here when ever `InterruptedException` occurs just reset the flag so that the
`while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {` can act accordingly. Which is the way we should deal with this. Hope it helps.

```
public class ThreadSync {

    private static int count = 100;
    private static Semaphore printSomeOnes = new Semaphore(1);
    private static Semaphore printSomeTwos = new Semaphore(0);
    private static Semaphore printSomeFours = new Semaphore(0);
    private static Semaphore printSomeEights = new Semaphore(0);
    private static volatile boolean runFlag = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create and start each runnable
        Runnable task1 = new TaskPrint1();
        Runnable task2 = new TaskPrint2();
        Runnable task3 = new TaskPrint4();
        Runnable task4 = new TaskPrint8();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(task1);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(task2);
        Thread thread3 = new Thread(task3);
        Thread thread4 = new Thread(task4);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();



        // Let them run for 500ms
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // put up the stop sign
//    runFlag=false;

        thread4.interrupt();
        thread3.interrupt();
        thread2.interrupt();
        thread1.interrupt();

    }

    public static class TaskPrint1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    if (i % 8 == 0) {
                        try {
                            printSomeOnes.acquire();
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.printf("%s\n", "1");
                    if (i % 8 == 0) {
                        printSomeTwos.release();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

public static class TaskPrint2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (i % 4 == 0) {
                    try {
                        printSomeTwos.acquire();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.printf("%s\n", "2");
                if (i % 4 == 0) {
                    printSomeFours.release();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class TaskPrint4 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    try {
                        printSomeFours.acquire();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                       Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.printf("%s\n", "4");
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    printSomeEights.release();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class TaskPrint8 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                try {
                    printSomeEights.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                   Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    break;
                }
                System.out.printf("%s\n", "8");
                printSomeOnes.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```